# Maintaining multiple versions of the same library with incompatible changes

Tags: maven

Ours a complex enterprise app and we use one third party library which we would like upgrade.But we do want to maintain two versions atleast for couple of releases till we are good with the newer version and switch which version to use by a configuration property.

We are trying maven shading for the same.

However the problem we are facing is like this. The changes between the two releases are very drastic. For example A is a class in version 1.0 and is now an interface in version 2.0

So let us say for example in the existing client code we say
A a = new A();
This would have to be changed to some other call in the new version.

Are there any ideas on how to make the client code compatible with both the versions?

Answer (score 0):

I **don't believe** there is a way to write code compatible with both the versions.

Keeping multiple versions of same jar may create **maintenance** nightmares.

I suggest to create/maintain **separate SVN branches** for each version of this jar.

You can decide which SVN branch should go into production based on maturity of that branch.

You can simply **replace the war from other branch**, if any issue during deployment/in production.